# Psycopg2 - How to Do Large Query - 1 Million Plus Rows

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, list, psycopg2, server-side

So i'm trying to do a massive query from a postgresql database that I have locally.

The 'processrecords' function, returns a listofmalwareobjects, i'm assuming i'll need to add a new list to a master list every time the server side cursor is run.

How would I do this properly as i'm a little confused.

I think I need to use server side cursors as otherwise the program runs out of memory with Psycopg2. But i've heard good things about server side cursors.

```
with connection:

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    with cursor:
        cursor.itersize = 20000
        cursor.execute("SELECT malware_id, malwarehashmd5, malwarehashsha1, malwarehashsha256g FROM malwarehashesandstrings")
        listoffetchedmalware = cursor.fetchall()


        listofmalwareobjects = processrecords(listoffetchedmalware)
```

Comment: Fetch **all** from cursor..?? More than one million rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [the documentation](http://psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors):

> Psycopg wraps the database server side cursor in named cursors. A named cursor is created using the cursor() method specifying the *name* parameter.

Try:

```
with connection:

    cursor = connection.cursor('my_cursor')
    ...
```

However, `fetchall()` will still return all rows at once. If you want to process the data in buckets, use [`fetchmany()`](http://psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchmany) in a loop, e.g.

```
with connection.cursor(name="my_cursor") as cursor:

    cursor.itersize = 20000
    cursor.execute(the_query)
    
    listoffetchedmalware = cursor.fetchmany(cursor.itersize)
    
    while len(listoffetchedmalware) > 0:
    
        listofmalwareobjects = processrecords(listoffetchedmalware)
        listoffetchedmalware = cursor.fetchmany(cursor.itersize)
```

Comment: your suggestion seems to mostly work, however i'm left with the problem here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57542860/psycopg2-fetching-of-rows-fetches-too-many-rows